# c++ how to assert that all std::shared_ptr in a vector are referring to something

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr, assert

When I have a function receiving a (smart) pointer that is supposed to refer something, I always start as follows:

```
class Foo;
void doSomething(const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& pFoo)
{
    assert(pFoo);
    // ...
}
```

Now I am looking for a similar assert condition for a vector (or other container) of (smart) pointers. The best I could come up with is:

```
void doSomething(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >& pFoos)
{
    assert(std::all_of(pFoos.begin(), pFoos.end(), [](const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& pFoo) { return pFoo; }));
    // ...
}
```

I wonder whether this could be improved.. can the lambda be avoided? (I tried to use the get() method of shared_ptr but template deduction fails then) Or is there another way to assert for a whole container?

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't change your function's syntax to receive a `Foo&` instead?  After all, that _guarantees_ there is an object and no assert is required.  Similarly with the vector, which could contain `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`.

Comment: `assert(!std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), nullptr));`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That visits all the elements, whereas we can break out when the first one that doesn't satisfy a condition is found.

Comment: @juanchopanza The program terminates due to assertion failure, if there is an element that does not satisfy conditions, and visits all elements in every other case. Is there really a need to make that one final check to run faster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

one more way to do it:

```
assert(std::find(pFoos.begin(), pFoos.end(), nullptr) == pFoos.end());
```

Answer (score 9):

Another slightly convoluted way to express it with standard functionality only:

```
assert(std::none_of(pFoos.begin(), pFoos.end(), std::logical_not<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>{}));
```

From C++14 onwards, you can use the generic specialization of `std::logical_not`:

```
assert(std::none_of(pFoos.begin(), pFoos.end(), std::logical_not<>{}));
```

Comment: this solution works only for c++14 and it does not work for c++11

Answer (score 1):

You could use implement your own utility predicate:

```
struct is_nullptr
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(T&& x) const noexcept { return x == nullptr; }
};

void doSomething(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >& pFoos)
{
    assert(!std::any_of(pFoos.begin(), pFoos.end(), is_nullptr{});
    // ...
}
```

---

And/or your own "range assertion":

```
template <typename TContainer, typename TPredicate>
void range_assert(TContainer&& container, TPredicate&& p)
{
    for(auto&& x : container)
    {
        assert(p(x));
    }
}

void doSomething(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >& pFoos)
{
    range_assert(pFoos, [](const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& x) { return x; });
    // ...
}
```