# How to use assert to check whether a weak_ptr is nullptr

Tags: c++, assert, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

The use of assert for checking whether a shared_ptr is not nullPtr is explained in  [c++ how to assert that all std::shared_ptr in a vector are referring to something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037465/c-how-to-assert-that-all-stdshared-ptr-in-a-vector-are-referring-to-somethin) but I don't find a decent way to check the same for a weak_ptr. I try to avoid converting it to shared_ptr so pls let me know your other solutions.

Comment: Possibly the same: [How to check if weak_ptr is empty (non-assigned)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507041/how-to-check-if-weak-ptr-is-empty-non-assigned)

Comment: weak_ptr::expired. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired

Comment: If you mean to use the [`assert` macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), note that it's "disabled" (expands to nothing) on typical release builds. It will also "crash" your program if it fails. Therefore it shouldn't really be used for run-time check in production builds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i just use to for the development.

Comment: Be careful: a `shared_ptr` cannot **be** `nullPtr` (if I'm reading the intent of that name correctly). It can **hold** a null pointer. With a `weak_ptr` there are two possible ways that it might not refer to actual memory: the `shared_ptr`s that it's associated with might hold a null pointer or it might not be associated with any `shared_ptr`s. So there isn't anything that's "the same", but two things that are similar. You'll have to say which one you mean, or you'll get guesses instead of actual answers.

Comment: @AF_cpp can you post your comment as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether the referenced model has already been deleted or whether the weak reference is empty -> use std::weak_ptr::expired().

reference documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired